# auto-completion in ace.js editor

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, editor, ace-editor

I would like to know if it's possible to enable auto-completion while user is typing in editor ace.js.
At the moment in my project auto-completion is enabled when user type: ctrl + space .
Then, is possible adding some keywords in the auto-completion list?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For triggering autocomplete [use](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ace-discuss/j4a17BvhBGI/zjPxmdNYO1YJ)

```
editor.commands.on("afterExec", function(e){
     if (e.command.name == "insertstring"&&/^[\w.]$/.test(e.args)) {
         editor.execCommand("startAutocomplete")
     }
})
```

For addidng some keywords you can either add another [completer](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/62c514135d5ebd912c3a0c8e7c200b59ad0f6fca/lib/ace/ext/language_tools.js#L70-L73) to the editor or override [getCompletions](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/62c514135d5ebd912c3a0c8e7c200b59ad0f6fca/lib/ace/ext/language_tools.js#L42) method on the mode.

Comment: Thanks! It shows autocomplete while the user is typing, but it also automatically replaces typed words when there's only one match in the auto-complete options. There's a way of avoiding this?

Comment: @Proghero did you ever find an answer to your question? I have the same issue.

Comment: Latest ace version have built in support for this see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/4599dc6/lib/ace/ext/language_tools.js#L150

Comment: I'm also haveing an issue with it automatically replacing typed words when there's only one match in the auto-complete options...where can I put `editor.completer.autoInsert = false;`? I have the latest version of ace included, but it is still autocompleting.

Answer (score 4):

It's already built in! See the options that I chose under `editor.setOptions`:

```
    var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");

    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/yaml");

    editor.setOptions({
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableSnippets: true,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true
    });
```